# codeiginiter always shows 404 error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I done a project using codeiginiter in windows(XAMPP), now i changed my OS to UBUNTU 14.04 and i have installed LAMP and LAMP works fine.

i copied my project files  to /var/www/html and changed all the configurations to ububtu

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/lankaproperty/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

**routes**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = 'home/error_404';
$route['500_override'] = 'home/error_500';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

i have also changed all the file permissions to 755..

when i try the default controller like this
   http://localhost/lankaproperty/
it works fine..

but none of the other controller is working

http://localhost/lankaproperty/home

http://localhost/lankaproperty/index.php?/home

i get the error.

`
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
`
can someone help me to fix this issue tnx..

**etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
    # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
    # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
    # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
    # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
    # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
    # access here, or in any related virtual host.
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

**sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html



        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**sites-avalible/000-default.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html



        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Have you tried in your routes to add  `$route['home'] = "home/index";` home would be the controller name

Comment: yes tried, but still the same 404 error.

Comment: yes i tried without question mark also. no change..

Comment: Thank you everyone. i migrated from codeiginiter 3.0 to codeiginiter 2.2.. now everything works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Replace the value from these two section in config file.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/lankaproperty/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Hope is usefull for u.

Answer (score 0):

Try code from [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html):

```
//config.php
$config['index_page'] = '';

//.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Try also with additional forward slash in line: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` , default controller also don't work..

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite is enabled in apache.

Comment: Set `RewriteBase /` just bellow `RewriteEngine On` and that in case your application is in root directory. Check logs in application and in apache too.